# Error: Script error for "main"

Tags: aurelia

I'm creating a project using Aurelia CLI and Express.

I've created a folder called "public", and there is also a folder called "js" inside "public". The "js" folder contains 'vendor-bundle.js' and 'app-bundle.js'.

My app.js file has the following code:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

My index.html:

```
<body aurelia-app="main">
    <script src="js/vendor-bundle.js" data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper">     </script>
</body>
```

My aurelia.json:

```
{
  "name": "master-the-toefl",
  "type": "project:application",
  "platform": {
    "id": "web",
    "displayName": "Web",
    "output": "public/js"
  },
  "transpiler": {
    "id": "babel",
    "displayName": "Babel",
    "fileExtension": ".js",
    "options": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-modules-amd"
      ]
    },
    "source": "src/**/*.js"
  },
  "markupProcessor": {
    "id": "none",
    "displayName": "None",
    "fileExtension": ".html",
    "source": "src/**/*.html"
  },
  "cssProcessor": {
    "id": "none",
    "displayName": "None",
    "fileExtension": ".css",
    "source": "src/**/*.css"
  },
  "editor": {
    "id": "sublime",
    "displayName": "Sublime"
  },
  "unitTestRunner": {
    "id": "none",
    "displayName": "None"
  },
  "paths": {
    "root": "src",
    "resources": "src/resources",
    "elements": "src/resources/elements",
    "attributes": "src/resources/attributes",
    "valueConverters": "src/resources/value-converters",
    "bindingBehaviors": "src/resources/binding-behaviors"
  },
  "build": {
    "targets": [
      {
        "id": "web",
        "displayName": "Web",
        "output": "public/js"
      }
    ],
    "loader": {
      "type": "require",
      "configTarget": "vendor-bundle.js",
      "includeBundleMetadataInConfig": "auto",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "extensions": [
            ".html",
            ".css"
          ],
          "stub": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "options": {
      "minify": "stage & prod",
      "sourcemaps": "dev & stage"
    },
    "bundles": [
      {
        "name": "app-bundle.js",
        "source": [
          "[**/*.js]",
          "**/*.{css,html}"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "vendor-bundle.js",
        "prepend": [
          "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",
          "scripts/require.js"
        ],
        "dependencies": [
          "aurelia-binding",
          ......
```

It should work. However, my console shows these errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/public/js/app-bundle.js
```

and

```
vendor-bundle.js:3297 Error: Script error for "main"(…)
```

What do I have to do to solve it?

Comment: can you post the contents of main.js please?

Comment: I have also found this when I tried to run the project on OSX when it previously worked in Windows.  Done an npm install etc.  Not sure what this is about

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to this github issue: [github issue](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/332)

This was fixed 2 days ago, so an update might fix your issue